# Does ExecuteSqlRaw() require SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

If I execute some SQL:

```
await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync();
```

Does that then need a call to:

```
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Does anyone know if this is clearly documented somewhere? I'm having difficulty finding it.

Comment: It depends. If ExecuteSqlRawAsync is based on data which is recorder only in ChangeTracker - yes execute SaveChanges first. EF do not do any implicit movements when you call ExecuteSqlRawAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are unrelated.  Raw SQL Queries can change the database directly.  Modified entities in the change tracker change the database on SaveChanges.

Comment: I think to add to the 2nd part of the question requesting for documentation,
it is defined as "Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected.". Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-6.0